# need some help on multy file upload

Tags: php, mysql, file-upload

i have this code

```
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file1']['tmp_name'], $upload_directory . $filename)){
//http file
    $fullurl = $siteurl.'/'.$upload_directory.'/'.$filename;
    //insert db
    mysql_query("insert into up_guest(name,type,time,ip) values('$filename','$filetype',$time,'$ip')");
    print "<br><br>";
    print "فایل با موفقیت آپلود شد!";
    print "<br><br>";
    print "<font color='black'>Uploaded File is {$filename} and its size is {$_FILES['file1']['size']} bytes </font>";
}//file upload she
else{
    echo $_FILES['file1']['error'];
}
```

its run if and upload file Successfully without any error
ANDDDDDDDDDDDDD run else too !!!
and file error is 0 !
what is the problem?

Comment: add && $_FILES['file1']['error'] == 0 in if condition..

Comment: move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file1']['tmp_name'], $upload_directory . $filename) and $_FILES['file1']['error'] == 0 not work still

Comment: Moving the directory exists and is writable?

Comment: mysql_query("insert into up_guest(name,type,time,ip) values('$filename','$filetype',$time,'$ip')")or die(mysql_error());  modify this line and share updated code and error if any..and also turn error_reporting so you will see all possible errors.

Comment: @XingjiaLuo he clearly said file is uploading correctly.

Comment: yes its worked fine after restart apache :| php in windows = WTF :D anyway thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multi-file upload array
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file1']['tmp_name'], $upload_directory . $filename) This is not the lack of '/'

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file1']['tmp_name'], $upload_directory .'/' . $filename)
```

I see you have the next line of code using the '/'

Comment: i add it but still run if and run else too !

Comment: damn its worked now after restarting apache! windows php is sux !